# How to save a executed query into a big query table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a subset of loyal customers queried in Google big query. I want to convert the query into a table.

I pressed Query Settings > Set a Destination table for query results but it shows invalid in Google Big Query.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot? I was able to set a destination table and save the results too

Answer (score 1):

Take your query and surround it with the following SQL

```
CREATE TABLE loyal_customers AS (

<your query here> 

);
```

and it will create your table. See more here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#sql_1